# Update table with SUM from another table

Tags: mysql, sum

I am trying to what I thought was going to be a simple update of a table with the sum from another table, but for some reason, it is only updating one row. Here is what the relevant info from the tables look like:

**games**

```
gameplayer|points
----------------
John      |5
Jim       |3
John      |3
Jim       |4
```

**playercareer**

```
playercareername|playercareerpoints
-----------------------------------
John            |0
Jim             |0
```

Now ultimately, I would like the last table to look like this after running the update:

**playercareer**

```
playercareername|playercareerpoints
-----------------------------------
John            |8
Jim             |7
```

This is the query I attempted that only updates the first row:

```
UPDATE playercareer
SET playercareer.playercareerpoints = 
    (
SELECT 
    SUM(games.points) 
FROM games
    WHERE
     playercareer.playercareername=games.gameplayer
    )
```

I can't seem to find the answer to this. Thanks in advance for your time and advice!

Comment: Sorry, I am using MySQL 5.5.16.

Comment: I tested your code with SQL Server and it works fine (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97125/2). Maybe you should verify your player names (maybe one has a white space and the match cannot be made). Ultimately, I'd recommand you use IDs instead of Names and use a relational table.

Comment: Oh well, still works fine with MySQL 5.5! (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97125/1)

Comment: This is odd. @FrancisP's sqlfiddle looks perfect. @BigJay, maybe the issue is related to the way your tables are structured? Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE games` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE playercareer`?

Comment: This isn't a particularly good idea. You're adding redundancy to your database by adding data which it already contains. Is there a reason you can't select the SUM when you need it?

Comment: WOW! Just discovered sqlfiddle here in the comments... fantastic tool!

Comment: I just tried the suggestion made by Francis and added a new column to each table called playerid and playercareerid. Populated those fields so the ID's match the playernames, updated my query, re-ran it and it worked like it should have. So Francis was probably right in the fact there may be a match error somewhere. 

@Jim This is a very casual database with at max 7 users with an update frequency of about a month apart. This data is relayed to a PHP page. I am certain there are more appropriate approaches, but I am still quite a beginner and hopefully learn more as I go. Thanks Francis!

Comment: this is great but what if we have million rows on both the tables. Which fields should we consider for indexing ?

Answer (score 49):

```
UPDATE playercareer c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT gameplayer, SUM(points) as total
  FROM games
  GROUP BY gameplayer
) x ON c.playercareername = x.gameplayer
SET c.playercareerpoints = x.total
```

Comment: hey @bobwienholt this is great but what if we have million rows on both the tables. Which fields should we consider for indexing ?

Comment: It does not matter how many rows you have; the most helpful thing you can do, if possible, is to index the field(s) you are using to join your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not same table names but this worked for me

```
update e
set e.Absence_Hours = a.hours
from [Thomas_Test].[dbo].Employee e
inner join (select empnum
                 , sum(hours) as hours
            FROM [Thomas_Test].[dbo].[Employee_Absence_Report]
            group by empnum) a 
        on a.empnum = e.emp_no;
```