# Updating one table Using data from another table in SQL

Tags: sql, join

Excuse me; I read couple of same questions but still couldn't figure out the solution.

I have two tables

`photo` table:

```
userID | photoID| score
```

`users` table:

```
userID | totalScore
```

I want to pass the `photoID` unique value to photo table (I mean I want to use only that value as an input variable in the query).

Then get the corresponding `userID` in the photos table

Then use the resulting unique `userID` in the users table to update `totalScore` such as

```
totalScore = totalScore + score
```

In another words lets say my values are

photo table:

```
userID | photoID| score
bob    |    5   | 500
```

users table:

```
userID | totalScore
bob    |    5000
```

I want the users table to look like after a query with an input of `photoId=5`

```
userID | totalScore
bob    |    5500
```

Hope I am clear enough.

___________________________EDIT________________________

https://stackoverflow.com/a/707668/842644

this one helped. It is possible that not every server supports update-join notation. wanted to share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update users 
set totalScore = totalScore + p.score
from users left join photo p on users.userId = p.userId
where p.photoID = 5
```

Comment: This looks like what I want but I am having syntax errors. I will try to fix

Comment: I think this part  
 
update users 
set totalScore = totalScore + p.score


is causing trouble so far (i can work the other part by using SELECT)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to update based on another table, but you would probally want some way to determine if it has already been updated or not.

```
UPDATE users
SET totalScore = TotalScore+tphoto.score
FROM users tuser
INNER JOIN photo tphoto ON tuser.userid = tphotos.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that total score should be the sum of all of a users points from the photo table

```
UPDATE users 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT userID, SUM(photo) as 'total' FROM photo GROUP BY userID) 
    x ON x.userID=users.userID 
SET users.totalScore=x.total
```

I didn't have a table to run that against.  I recommend using [sequel pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) or another tool that can give error messages if you have mysql syntax issues.  I would also recommend you use an auto incrementing integer as the key you use to map between the 2 tables.  Each user should have a unique integer id.  That way if you have two bobs there is no problem.

Here is another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091336/update-table-with-sum-from-another-table) that might provide further insight.

Edit: if you just want to update bob add this to the end

```
WHERE userId='bob'
```